# How can I control which public key adb uses to authenticate a given command?

Tags: android, authentication, cmd, adb, rsa

ADB is using adbkey and adbkey.pub within my *USER*/.android directory to authenticate when I connect to a device. I want to be able to use a different key - perhaps within that folder or within a different directory - to authenticate some commands, is there any way to tell it to use a different key to adbkey?

I know there is an environment variable $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS that is described in the help section but it already knows where to find the key because it's finding the original one, but it doesn't seem to try to authenticate using the other keys there when the original one fails.
I've looked all the way through the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb, and many rabbit-holes of SO questions and forum pages but unless I'm being very blind I can't find anything that helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Not a great answer, but thought I'd post the solution that I'll be using just in case it helps someone.

The ADB server seems to only be able to cope with using one rsa key at a time - it has to be called adbkey/adbkey.pub and it has to be in the .android folder. Nothing I did to $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS seemed to change anything.

What did work, is that you can kill the server `adb kill-server` and then delete the key already in the folder, then restart the server `adb start-server`, then you can use the different key that is generated during the `start-server` bit. It's not exactly a perfect solution, but I can just about make it work for my use-case.